# Как узнать какой клавишей мыши была нажата кнопка?

Tags: c#, wpf, button

Как в событии Button_Click определять, какая кнопка мыши была нажата?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы определить какая кнопка мыши была нажата, вы можете использовать свойство [SystemParameters.SwapButtons](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemparameters.swapbuttons(v=vs.85).aspx%20SystemParameters.SwapButtons)

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (SystemParameters.SwapButtons) 
        {
            // Была нажата правая кнопка
        }
        else
        {
            // Была нажата левая кнопка

        }
    }
```

Но учтите, это событие вызывается только при нажатии ***основной*** кнопки.
Об этом сказано по ссылке на английский SO в одном из ответов.

Из вопроса не совсем ясно, такой ли ответ вы хотели получить.
Если вам нужно в одном методе обрабатывать разные клики по одной кнопке, то предлагаю использовать другой подход, который больше подходит для WPF. А именно - команды.

В качестве примера предположим, что у вас есть некоторое число, которые вы хотите уменьшать на единицу при нажатии правой кнопки и увеличивать на единицу при нажатии левой кнопки.

Пишите простую `VM`:

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int count;
    public int Count
    {
        get { return count; }
        set { count = value; OnPropertyChanged("Count"); }
    }

    private ICommand clickCommand;
    public ICommand ClickCommand
    {
        get { return clickCommand; }
        set { clickCommand = value; }
    }

    public void buttonClick(object param)
    {
        int value = Convert.ToInt32(param);
        if (value == 0)
            Count++;
        else if (value == 1)
            Count--;
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        clickCommand = new RelayCommand(buttonClick);
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

Наш метод принимает параметр, который показывает какая кнопка была нажата. Если `0`- левая, если `1` - правая. Эти значения были выбраны произвольно, вы можете передавать в объект то, что посчитаете нужным.

Теперь XAML:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Button Margin="10"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Content="Click">
        <Button.InputBindings>
            <MouseBinding Command="{Binding ClickCommand}"
                          CommandParameter="0"
                          Gesture="LeftClick" />
            <MouseBinding Command="{Binding ClickCommand}"
                          CommandParameter="1"
                          Gesture="RightClick" />
        </Button.InputBindings>
    </Button>
    <TextBlock Margin="10" Text="{Binding Count}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Для того, что определить какое действие нужно обработать используется [Gesture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mousebinding.gesture(v=vs.110).aspx):
Чтобы узнать возможные варианты нужно обратится к перечислению [MouseAction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mouseaction(v=vs.110).aspx)

Код для RelayCommand не привожу, чтобы не загромождать ответ. Но вы без труда сможете найти подходящую реализацию. Например, [тут](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/813345/Basic-MVVM-and-ICommand-Usage-Example)

Если код показался слишком большим - не пугайтесь ;) В дальнейшем вы будете пользоваться специальными библиотеками (например, [FSharpViewModule](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharp.ViewModule) для F# - проектов) или даже фреймверками ([Prism](https://habrahabr.ru/post/176851/)) для крупных проектов которые упростят разработку.

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснение

Answer (score 1):

Cначала приводите event к `MouseEventArgs`:

```
MouseEventArgs me = (MouseEventArgs) e;
```

Потом смотрите на:

```
me.Button
```

Либо посмотреть тут - для WPF [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/977329/how-can-i-determine-which-mouse-button-raised-the-click-event-in-wpf)

Comment: if (m.RightButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
                    MessageBox.Show("The Right Mouse Button is pressed");
Делаю так - программа крашится

Comment: Не удалось привести тип объекта "System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs" к типу "System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs".

Answer (score 1):

Отвечает за это событие MouseEventArgs

Comment: ах, опоздал я с ответом...

Answer (score 1):

Я относительно новичок и могу не знать всех тонкостей, но по-моему для определения кнопки проще использовать событие MouseDown:

```
  private void button_MouseDown( object sender, MouseEventArgs e )
    {
        if(e.Button==MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            //Нажата правая кнопка
        }
        else if(e.Button==MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            //Нажата левая кнопка
        }
        else
        {
            //Нажата средняя кнопка
        }
    }
```