# Как узнать какой клавишей мыши была нажата кнопка? WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, button

Как в событии Button_Click определять, какая кнопка мыши была нажата? Попытался воспользоваться советами, данными в вопросе [Вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/589578/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%88%D0%B8-%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B0), но они не помогли:

```
MouseEventArgs me = (MouseEventArgs) e;
```

Не удалось привести тип объекта "System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs" к типу "System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs".
А при использовании этого:

```
if (SystemParameters.SwapButtons) 
        {
            // тут код
        }
        else
        {
            // тут код
        }
```

работала только левая кнопка мыши,при нажатии на правую ничего не происходило. Так как же программно определить внутри события OnClick кнопки, какая из клавишей мыши была нажата?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно подписать кнопку на событие `PreviewMouseDown`, и убрать подписку на `Click` потому, что `Click` завязан на системные настройки мыши (какая кнопка мыши выбрана рабочей, т.е. левша человек или правша).

```
private void Button_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Левая");
        }
        if (e.RightButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Правая");
        }
    }
```